# button click inside Usercontrol for load another usercontrol in main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have main form and 2 usercontrols.The main form contains split container, In splitcontainer.panel1 i loaded UserControl1. In usercontrol different buttons are placed. I wants to load usercontrol2 on panel2(in main form) on button clicks which are placed inside the usercontrol1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserControl1 obj = new UserControl1();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(obj);
    }
}

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public event EventHandler ButtonClick;
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

On button1_Click i want to load UserControl2 on form splitcontainer panel2

Comment: A [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help

Comment: Please show some sample code so we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your UserControl1 like this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(ButtonClick != null)
        ButtonClick(this, e);
}
```

And then in your Form1 constructor add the following code:

```
obj.ButtonClick += (Sender, e) => 
{
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(obj2);
};
```

This should work